# Find the divergence of the field F: $\vec{F} = \frac{yj - zk}{\sqrt{y^2+ z^2}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

> Find the divergence of the field F:
>   $$\vec{F} = \frac{yj - zk}{\sqrt{y^2+ z^2}}$$

Normally I find dot the gradient with F like this:

$$\langle 0,y,-z\rangle\cdot\langle F_x, F_y, F_z\rangle$$

And this simplifies to:

$$\langle 0, 1, -1\rangle$$

And then I tried dividing each component of the answer  by:

$$\sqrt{y^2 +z^2},$$

but that isn't correct according to the answer in the back of my book.

How do I go about properly solving this? Thanks

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage: $$\begin{align} \textbf{right: } & \langle 0,y,-z\rangle\cdot\langle F_x, F_y, F_z\rangle \\ \\ \textbf{wrong: } & < 0,y,-z> \bullet< F_x, F_y, F_z > \end{align} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\nabla \cdot \vec F=\frac {\partial F_x}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial F_y}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial F_z}{\partial z}=0+\frac{z^2}{(y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}+\frac{-y^2}{(y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: But is, for example, $F_y = y$ or it also includes the denominator?

Comment: It includes the denominator, if it makes it clearer, you can think of $\vec F=F_x\hat i+F_y\hat j+F_z\hat k$. Therefore, in this case, we would have $F_x=0$,$F_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt {y^2+z^2}}$ and $F_z=-\frac{z}{\sqrt {y^2+z^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla \cdot (0\mathbf i + \frac {y}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\mathbf j - \frac {z}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\mathbf k) = \frac {\partial}{\partial x}0+\frac {\partial}{\partial y}\frac {y}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} + \frac {\partial}{\partial z} \frac {-z}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\\
0+\frac {2y^2 + z^2}{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 32}-\frac {y^2 + 2z^2}{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 32} = \frac {y^2-z^2}{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 32}$

alternate

$\nabla \cdot \left((0\mathbf i + y\mathbf j - z\mathbf k) \left(\frac 1{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 12}\right)\right)\\
\left(\nabla\cdot(0,y,-z)\right)\left(\frac 1{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 12}\right) +(0,y,-z)\cdot \nabla \left(\frac 1{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 12}\right) \\
0 + \left(\frac {(0,y,-z)\cdot(0,y,z)}{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 32}\right)\\
\frac {y^2-z^2}{(y^2+z^2)^\frac 32}$